# How to connect a MS acess file(MDB file) to asp.net webform?

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

Is this connection string correct?

**`con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=k:\Users\kaarthick\documents\visual studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite8\Database\Database1.mdb;";`**

Are password and userId mandatory to be in connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an older version of office access. Anyways, that looks a valid connection string and No, password not always mandatory. A valid connection string example below

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

See more information on

[Connection String Sample](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

[DoFactory Example](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings)

[MSDN Forum Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce4bdc40-6955-4e06-a7a5-41ae5135027a/connecting-ms-access-database-in-c)